# Writing to file storage

Tags: android, file, kotlin, storage, android-external-storage

I want to write files to external storage and when i look at the `usableSpace` for `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` it says that it's only 515.74MB.

Is this the typical `usableSpace` size of a directory? What if you needed more storage space to write to, how would you handle that scenario?

```
private fun getStorageDirectory(): File {
    return if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    } else {
        context.filesDir
    }
}


private fun getUsableSpace(): Long {
    return getStorageDirectory()?.usableSpace ?: 0L
}
```

### Update

When testing on an emulator the usableSpace for different storage directories are as follows

```
DEBUG ~~ [context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).usableSpace 515739648] 515.74MB
DEBUG ~~ [context.getExternalFilesDir(null).usableSpace 515739648] 515.74MB
DEBUG ~~ [context.filesDir.usableSpace 515739648] 515.74MB
DEBUG ~~ [context.externalCacheDir.usableSpace 515735552] 515.74MB
DEBUG ~~ [context.cacheDir.usableSpace 515735552] 515.74MB
```

When testing on an Google Pixel XL the usableSpace for different storage directories are as follows

```
DEBUG ~~ [context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).usableSpace 79697793024] 79.70GB
DEBUG ~~ [context.getExternalFilesDir(null).usableSpace 79697793024] 79.70GB
DEBUG ~~ [context.filesDir.usableSpace 79697793024] 79.70GB
DEBUG ~~ [context.externalCacheDir.usableSpace 79697764352] 79.70GB
DEBUG ~~ [context.cacheDir.usableSpace 79697760256] 79.70GB
```

So i guess on a real device you have much more space to write to.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace? Did you try this in your emulator or phone? Most of the emulators have less internal storage.

Comment: did you try to write the files in internal storage if you dont want to show files to user?

Comment: Directories have no space size. There is only a partition  size. To every directory on a partition you can write until the partition is 'full'.

Comment: The directories you mentioned are mostly on different partitions. You did not give the size of both.

Comment: @MADLAD this 498MB was on an emulator. I will report back as to what that number is on a real device.

There was no stack trace. It wasn't an error.  I however will do a check on the usable space and if i dont have enough usable space then i wont write to a file.

Comment: @Quicklearner i have not tried to write the files to internal storage because i though that would fill up really fast and i wanted enough space to write these files.

Comment: @blackapps So after looking at the documentation it says that getUsableSpace() returns the number of available bytes on the partition.  If thats the case, then does it even matter which Environment type you provide to the getExternalFilesDir() method?

Comment: @toobsco42 these days devices have enough storage as primary storage which is internal storage which cant be mounted like great devices have 64 gb , its better to use the internal storage , when the app is unistalled all the data is removed automatically

Comment: @blackapps I will print out the available bytes on the partition for both internal and external storage on an emulator as well as a real device and will update this post.